# I am unable to install pillow file and currently using python 3.5.1, also having an error while coding, the error is NameError

Tags: python, django

Also while coding its not identifying models, even i have added apps file of models in settings.

Also am unable to install pillow file and when i am checking django version its showing the command Found Exception, it was working till yesterday and now its not working stuck in between don't know why so?

I have tried several things to resolve the same but nothing is happening and its so frustrating that i am unable to solve this error.

File "d:/project/mysite/mysite/categorymodel.py", line 1, in 
    class Category(models.Model):
NameError: name 'models' is not defined

(myproject) D:\project\mysite\mysite>C:/Users/BTN-2/envs/myproject/Scripts/python.exe d:/project/mysite/mysite/categorymodel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/project/mysite/mysite/categorymodel.py", line 1, in 
    class Category(models.Model):
NameError: name 'models' is not defined

(myproject) D:\project\mysite\mysite>:/Users/BTN-2/envs/myproject/Scripts/python.exe d:/project/mysite/mysite/categorymodel.py
(myproject) D:\project\mysite\mysite>C:/Users/BTN-2/envs/myproject/Scripts/python.exe d:/project/mysite/mysite/categorymodel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/project/mysite/mysite/categorymodel.py", line 1, in 
    class Category(models.Model):
NameError: name 'models' is not defined

Comment: You've not imported `models` - `from django.db import models` should be before your model definition

Answer (score 0):

you got error from 1st line of models.py fix that with it first..

```
from django.db import models
```